# Mplot3D plot freezes when plotting in PyCharm Professional

Tags: matplotlib, pycharm, mplot3d

Recently when I am doing MatPlotLib 3D plots in PyCharm, the debugging and the plot window are freezing when excuting the plt.show() command. In the top bar of the plot is mentioned (Not Responding). This happens both in PyCharm Community edition 2019 and PyCharm Professional 2021. I am running v3.8 of Python. If I execute plt.show(Block=True), the interactive 3D plot will come up, but I will need to close the figure to continue the debugging.

Does anyone have an idea how I can plot the figure with plt.show(), get up the interactive window, and continue debugging while still having the interactive window open? This worked in my previous version of Python v3.7, but the problem happened recently when upgrading to v3.8.

Answer (score 10):

I recently faced the same issue when using matplotlib to plot. This seems to be related to a change in the order of precedence that matplotlib uses to pick its default backend. According to the `matplotlibrc` file that is bundled with the Python package, the order used to be

> MacOSX **Qt5Agg** Gtk3Agg TkAgg WxAgg Agg

in previous versions (e.g., v3.4.2), while in more recent versions (e.g., v3.5.0) it has been be changed to

> MacOSX **QtAgg** Gtk4Agg Gtk3Agg TkAgg WxAgg Agg

For me, setting the backend to `Qt5Agg` right after importing matplotlib in Python via

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("Qt5Agg")
```

indeed solved the "Not responding" issue. Alternatively, we can specify it through the environment variable `MPLBACKEND=Qt5Agg`.
Likely, we could also set `Qt5Agg` as default backend in `matplotlibrc` either by modifying the bundled `matplotlibrc` file or by providing our own.

PS: Not sure whether the core issue that prevents the `QtAgg` backend from working correctly is in PyCharm, matplotlib, or PyQt...

Comment: This worked for me as well, nearly two years later.