# matplotlib non responding with pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I have an annoying issue with matplotlib using Pycharm where the plot window doesn't respond and freezes or just shows the plot in the Sciview as a picture (so we don't see anything and impossible to zoom).

Here is my setup:

- Windows 10
- PyCharm Professional 2023.1.3
- matplotlib 3.5.3
- python 3.10.12

and I also use Anaconda

Here is my simple code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()
```

As a result, I get the graph in the SciView window, but formatted as a picture, meaning that I basically see nothing and can't. In brief, not what is expected.

After some research (see links below), I update my code writing:
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/23131
https://github.com/jupyter/qtconsole/issues/441
[Mplot3D plot freezes when plotting in PyCharm Professional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70964332/mplot3d-plot-freezes-when-plotting-in-pycharm-professional)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4])
plt.show()
```

I have also replaced 'QT5Agg' with 'QtAgg' or 'tkAgg' but as result I obtained a matplotlib window loading forever and not responding similarly to the problems mentioned in the links above.

Comment: In PyCharm 2023.2.1 with matplotlib 3.7.2, this is not reproducible.

Comment: I updated Pycharm version to 2023.2.1, it does the trick ! Thank you !